# Compare two datetimes - without hour and second

Tags: c#

As the title states, what's the best way to compare to DateTime's without hours and seconds?

I don't want to convert my dates to string, and a solution like

> `DateTime.Now.Year == last.Year &&
>   DateTime.Now.Month == last.Month &&
>   DateTime.Now.Day == last.Day`

is pretty damn ugly.

Edit: Oh my god, how silly I feel. Of course you can use the Date property.

"Another question": What is the best way to compare DateTime's with Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, but not seconds?

Thanks

Comment: To answer your other question, maybe you can muck around with .Ticks, scaling it down appropriately until it fits whatever size you want to measure. But I'd probably just go with the explicit method of checking the fields.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this: what you're looking for?

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property, then you can compare dt1.Date with dt2.Date.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Date property of DateTime object.

For example,
DateTime dateOne

dateOne.Date property will use only date part.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler than the accepted answer you can simply use:

```
DateTime.Today
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the comparison without seconds, just use this:

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoringSeconds(this DateTime source, DateTime target)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromTicks(source.Ticks).TotalMinutes == TimeSpan.FromTicks(target.Ticks).TotalMinutes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the 'another' question: you can create an extension for DateTime

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreSeconds(this DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    // the ugly code
}
```

but then using it is beautiful, e.g.: `DateTime.Now.EqualsIgnoreSeconds(b)`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
          DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
          int result = DateTime.Compare(date1.Date, date2.Date);
          string relationship;

          if (result < 0)
             relationship = "is earlier than";
          else if (result == 0)
             relationship = "is the same time as";         
          else
             relationship = "is later than";

          Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
        }
    }
}
```

This line is crucial:

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1.Date, date2.Date);
```