# How to Compare two date without timeline in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

I want to compare two dates. In pseudo-code:

```
If the dueDate > now or dueDate = now 

Then Fine Amount = something.

Else Fine Amount = 0
```

I wrote below code:

```
DateTime dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader1[3].ToString());
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int result = DateTime.Compare(dueDate, now);
if ((result < 0) || (result == 1))
{
    row["Fine_Amount"] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader1[4].ToString()); 
}
else
{
    row["Fine_Amount"] = 0;
}
```

This code gives wrong value, when

```
dueDate = 23-12-2011 AM 12:00:00
now = 23-12-2011 PM 05:26:54
```

I want to Compare:

```
dueDate = 23-12-2011
now = 23-12-2011
```

How do I remove the time in that?.

Adding below code is given result. But its to lengthy code.: -

```
 DateTime dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader1[3].ToString());
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                    if (dueDate.Year < now.Year)
                    {
                        row["Fine_Amount"] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader1[4].ToString());
                    }
                    else if (dueDate.Year > now.Year)
                    {
                        row["Fine_Amount"] = 0;
                    }
                    else if (dueDate.Year == now.Year)
                    {
                        if (dueDate.Month < now.Month)
                        {
                             row["Fine_Amount"] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader1[4].ToString();
                        }
                        else if(dueDate.Month > now.Month)
                        {
                             row["Fine_Amount"] = 0;
                        }
                        else if(dueDate.Month == now.Month)
                        {
                             if(dueDate.Day < now.Day)
                             {
                                 row["Fine_Amount"] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader1[4].ToString();
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 row["Fine_Amount"] = 0;
                             }
                        }
                    }
```

Is there any way to short this code?.

Answer For this Question is

```
if (dueDate.Date >= now.Date)
{
    row["Fine_Amount"] = 0;
}
else
{
    row["Fine_Amount"] = Convert.ToDouble(Reader1[4].ToString());
}
```

This datetime.date is gives

```
 dueDate = 23-12-2011 AM 12:00:00 to 23-12-2011 AM 12:00:00 
    now = 23-12-2011 PM 05:26:54 to 23-12-2011 AM 12:00:00
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two datetimes - without hour and second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286572/compare-two-datetimes-without-hour-and-second)

Comment: Thanks, At last i am using very lengthy and simple code to get my answer.

I am still believe, there is a easy way to get this result. May be i know feature. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Now.Date`

According to docs, [Date property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) returns: A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Comment: @Sagotharan What do you mean by remove the time? The Date property returns you the same structure without time, isn't this what you have asked for?

Comment: Oh thanks, And Forgive me, I didn't understand,.. And now only i check it out. 

I am excepting 24-12-2011 only. but 24-12-2011 AM 12:00:00 and 24-12-2011 same effect to compare. i am not understand that. So i add the above command. Thanks A lot.

Comment: @Sagotharan: Basically, you can compare with > operator, like: `Now.Date > yourDate`. Because you have your date without time, and Now.Date will just set time to 00:00:00, so H/M/S will always be equal to themselves

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime class in C# supports comparison by simply using `<`, `>`, and `==` operators. Do it like your above written pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

`dueDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date`

Although you could use the `.Date` property of `DateTime` it is generally a good practice to compare a certain date to a date range:

```
startDate <= someDate && someDate < endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to gets the date component of a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) value:

```
if (dueDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Date property of DateTime object for comparison